# Python - fill entire frame with tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to fill my frame with a button. It only fills width and does not fill height with this code:

```
    container.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    button1.pack(fill="both")
    button2.pack(fill="both")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how ti fill the intire height automatically. I mean without write the size of the button wiht button.config

Comment: You don't do that in your example

Comment: OK, what does mean "both" in this case? I thought it would fill the object in height and width?

Comment: `fill="both", expand=1` is the right way to do it but with `pack` you are only stating a wish and the geometry manager has to figure it out. For instance, multiple buttons in the same frame will have to battle it out. But also, you can't mix grid and pack. There are small examples in the docs that work... expand from there.

Comment: @doggdor What's your operating system? If I'm not wrong, tkinter (actually tk) uses native widgets, i.e. widgets provided by the operating system. This means that if your operating system does not allow you to create a button with a different height than the default one, then you won't be able to do what you want. A workaround would be to use a label or a frame as a button. You can listen to "on hover" and "on click" events and change for example the color of the widgets in the former case, etc.

Comment: do the widgets share a common parent, or are `button1` and `button2` children of `container`?

Comment: @BryanOakley: They are children of container.@tdelaney: Thank you, "expand=1" helps!